# In nginx config, how to show something to log file directly in the config file?

Tags: nginx

I'm config a nginx, and debugging the config file,

How to show something from the config file directly to log file?

for example:

```
location ..... {

   to_log "some string";

   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way (on the todo list of the echo nginx module), but this solution seems fine https://serverfault.com/questions/404626/how-to-output-variable-in-nginx-log-for-debugging

Comment: just fine isn't helpful when only a handful of people get the error and they're not tech savvy enough to view the headers, or are using devices where there is no facility outside of developer debug connections (iPad on Safari 13.1)

Same URL - he gets 404, I don't.  I'd love to log some things.

Comment: Thanks for that. It doesn't quite solve the problem though as these variables are logged at the request level-not inside nested logic.